# Rendering value inside <pre><code> when HTML being rendered as HTML not as code, not happening with other languages((ACF, php, twig)

Tags: php, acfpro

I am a frontend getting into backend, so for me this is totally new. So I am experimenting with ACF custom fields in Wordpress, and wanted to build my own simple "code" field(just in case, please, do not suggest another because I already tried one and I had conflicts with other libraries so that's why I decided to go and build it myself, and mainly they are out to day), in the frontend I am using twig and prism to get the things highlighted that works fine, but then in my backend (the important part) I have a custom field that receive the code, which is a "textarea", but put attention to me explanation first, and I have another one, called languages so I can filter the languages to display in the frontend mainly to highlight properly by rendering the right class, everything fine with it. BUT I realized when I have HTML, the value is rendering by the browser as html, with that being said I meant, instead of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting:

```
My first Heading My first paragraph
```

Now, just to clarify, I read about text areas having troubles with HTML and rendering strings instead so I made a test and in my custom ACF field I used (just for test) a div with contenteditable= "true" and it worked the same, which means is not a direct problem with the textarea. So I also tested in the backend to print the value so:

```
echo '<pre>'
print_r($field[value])
echo '</pre>'
```

and I always get the HTML rendered, now ...I also tried to parse the value inside two php functions which are htmlspecialchars() and the other one was html_entity_decode() but I am always having the same issue.

Also just to clarify in the frontend I have :

```
{% set bem = bem | extenBem('code-editor', alias) %}

{% block template %}
<pre class="{{ bem.classString }}">
<code>
{{ code }}
</code>
</pre>
{% endblock %}
```

In my ACF rendered function in the backend I have...

```
public function render_field($field){
  <textarea>
    name="<?php echo esc_atr($field['name']) ?>"
    <?php echo print_r($field['value']) ?>
  </texarea>
}
```

Please take into consideration what I mentioned before, what I tried or how I tried to parse the variable, so not just with print_r or echo.

An advice will be really appreciate and thank you in advice for reading.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you just need to escape the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code to use the `esc_textarea` function that will convert HTML characters to their respective `HTML entities`, so they are displayed as text rather than being rendered as HTML by the browser. Hope that helps!

```
public function render_field($field) {
  ?>
  <textarea name="<?php echo esc_attr($field['name']); ?>">
    <?php echo esc_textarea($field['value']); ?>
  </textarea>
  <?php
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer, sorry my mistake, I already used this function as well at the the beginning, but unfortunately did not work for me